# paillier encryption maximum ciphertext size

Tags: c++, public-key-encryption

I am familiar with most of the public key encryption on the theoretical side (whatever are explained in the Katz/Lindell book) but I do  not have any practical programming side with any of them.

My question is directly specific to Paillier's and its implementation.

I need to represent various radio configurations which have the formal below:

radio 1=[ch_1=1, ch_2=0, ch_3=0...,ch_32=1] which constitutes the configuration of a single radio consisting of 32 channels.  Each channel can be ON or OFF (1 or 0)

Each such configuration would thus require 32 bits of data.  If I were to want to represent 32 such radios in a "block" it would consist of 1024 bits of data.

The problem is that I have the need to represent almost 10 more times the amount of radio configurations in one block of data.  In other words, I need to represent close to 302 radio configurations, each consisting of 32 bits of data in a single "block" for a total of around 9664 bits of data per block.

I am told from colleagues that have more practical experience with Paillier that we cannot pack more than 1024 bits into a Paillier ciphertext.  I want to know if this statement is true (that it is impossible to pack more than 1024 bits into a Paillier ciphertext) and if so what is the reason behind it?  Perhaps packing more into the ciphertext would make it impractical to use from a computation standpoint?

We intend to use Paillier for a Private Information Retrieval scheme.

The implementation would most likely be done in C++

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like some other crypto systems, Paillier key generation starts out by picking two large primes `p,q` and setting `n=p*q`. Since messages have to be in `Z/nZ` (this denotes integeres modulo n), it is indeed correct that if you choose a 1024-bit implementation (i.e., `n` has 1024 bits), you can't encode messages larger than 1024 bits in a single step.

However, nothing prevents you from splitting your larger message into many smaller blocks and encrypting every block individually. In your case, the state of the first 32 radios would forn the first block, which you then encrypt and send. Repeat for the state of radios 33-64, etc etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Do you know the relation that the block size has in relation to the performance (computation efficiency) in Paillier from a practical standpoint?

In other words, why would one want to put in 32 radios vs 320 radios which might translate into say 10000 blocks vs 1000 blocks?

How does the correlation between block size/efficiency measured basically?

Comment: @user2799808 I have no benchmarks or anything similar. I do wonder though why you are so vigorously opposed to the idea of splitting your data into multiple messages? Pretty much every cryptosystem under the sun does exactly that!

Comment: @user2799808 The following may help you understand: In RSA, you need to compute `mod n`. In Paillier, `mod 2n`. So essentially, for 1024 bit Paillier, you need a 2048 bit integer type that you can do arithmetic with. Compare that with the 64 bit that you actually have in hardware and you realize that this is a complicated and time-consuming endeavour. If you want even larger key sizes, you need (a) much larger primes and (b) arithmetic with much larger numbers. This is why key sizes are large enough to prevent brute force attacks, but key size isn't increased just to make larger msg blocks.

Comment: The intuition (opposition) given to me is that if we split at 32 radios each, at a point where we hit the limits of Paillier's cipher text implemented with a security parameter of 1024 bits, then we would wind up with a LOT of ciphertexts to process, namely so many that it would be impractical to implement the PIR (private information retrieval) scheme.  

So packing more data into one ciphertext would be one way, but we can only go at 2048 bits security parameter not more.  Also, finding a "clever" way to represent a radio configuration of 32 bit channels with less data would be another way.

Comment: Hm. I'm afraid I don't know much about PIRs, so maybe I don't quite get what you're looking for. I'd say this may be a a question for crypto.stackexchange.com, but make sure to polish it a bit beforehands (for example, if all radio states are possible, you *cannot* represent 32 states by less than 32 bits. This is not about finding a *clever* way to still do it, it's an actual impossibility).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I think my observations are valid.

First of all: never use an asymmetric cipher as a block cipher. This has security and performance implications. If you need to encrypt large chunks of data, use a symmetric cipher (AES for example), it will perform much better and it is secure (if used properly) to be used as a block cipher. If you need, use the asymmetric cipher to exchange the symmetric key.

Now about Paillier. The amount of data you can encrypt with Paillier is limited to "n", non-inclusive. "n" is generated by picking two large primes "p" and "q", such that `n = p*q`. Then you must have the message `m < n`. That is, the message "m" should be smaller than "n". Suppose you have a text like: `radio`. You can represent it in binary as: `01110010 01100001 01100100 01101001 01101111 00001010`. If read `01110010 01100001 01100100 01101001 01101111 00001010` as a number, you get: `m = 125762622025482`. If you have `m < n`, then you can encrypt "m".

Now about this claim:

> I am told from colleagues that have more practical experience with
>   Paillier that we cannot pack more than 1024 bits into a Paillier
>   ciphertext.

It is WRONG. Paillier, like other asymmectric ciphers, will, in almost all cases, expand the size of the plaintext. That is, the size, in bits, of the ciphertext will be bigger than the size in bits of the plain text. What determines the maximum size of the plaintext and the cipher text is `n`, which is limited by the primes `p` and `q`. So, as long as you pick large enough primes, you can pack more than 1024 bits in a ciphertext. But bear in mind: as you increase the primes size, you will degrade performance. So you should find a good balance between performance and security when choosing the primes size. `n` with 3072 a good choice for Paillier.

To sum up: Don't use Paillier or any other asymmetric cipher as block a cipher. Use them to exchange symmetric keys, then use a symmetric cipher, with a good mode of operation (like CTR. Don't use ECB).